# Alternative of #include<iostream> in C++

Tags: c++

Why is is necessary to use iostream library while writing a program in C++. If i don't want to include this library, so what is the alternative of this iostream library.

Here is my code without including iostream. I tried to use include stdio.h but it does not work.

```
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void biodata ();

main()
{
    biodata ();
}

void biodata()
{
    cout << "Name: Ijlal Hussain.\nFather Name: Iftikhar Hussin.\nAge: 18. \nStudent of Comsats University Islamabad (Attock Campus)";
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use iostreams, your alternatives are C-style stdio and low level OS-specific functions like `write()` or `WriteFile()`. Oh, and your `main()` function needs to return `int`. That compiles without warnings for you?

Comment: In addition to the C-style IO and the OS-specific IO, you can use other libraries (which will in turn use C-style IO, iostreams, or OS-specific IO).

Comment: Why do you not want to include `<iostream>`? If you want to use `cout` etc., you need to include it (or include something which includes it); otherwise the compiler won't know what `cout` even is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use std::cout without  header so use printf instead with cstdio header .

```
#include<cstdio>
void biodata ();
main()
{
    biodata ();
}
void biodata()
{
    printf("Name: Ijlal Hussain.\nFather Name: Iftikhar Hussin.\nAge: 18. \nStudent of Comsats University Islamabad (Attock Campus)");
}
```

Comment: Using "conio.h" is non-standard and not a good recommendation.

Comment: @D.Go Even with platforms where `conio.h` is typical, it doesn't contain `printf` usually; you should include `cstdio` for that.

Comment: @DanielH Yes, so best avoided, either way ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<cstdio>` instead of `<iostream>`, if you just need to output text.

To print a string without formatting, you can use `puts`. Use `printf` to print with format and conversion specifiers.

```
#include<cstdio>

void biodata ();

int main()
{
  biodata ();
  return 0;
}

void biodata()
{    
   //using puts   
   puts("Name: Ijlal Hussain.\nFather Name: Iftikhar Hussin.\nAge: 18. \nStudent of Comsats University Islamabad (Attock Campus)");

   //using printf
    const char* name = "Ijlal Hussain";
    const char* fathername = "Iftikhar Hussin";
    int age = 18;
    printf("Name: %s.\nFather Name: %s.\nAge: %d. \nStudent of Comsats University Islamabad (Attock Campus)", name, fathername, age);     

}
```

Comment: I don't want to use syntax of c. I am writing the program in C++. You suggested code shows my statements twice in output.

Comment: @IjlalHussain P.W. is just showing you two ways of doing the same thing. You can use this example with `printf` and remove the `puts` line.

Comment: I want to use cout statement instead of printf. When i compile it, it shows error and you suggested syntax is about C language.

Comment: @IjlalHussain `cout` is part of `<iostream>`. If you aren't going to use `<iostream>` the you won't have access to it.

Comment: Furthermore, `printf` is just as valid in C++ as it is in C. The syntax uses C++ standards and there is nothing about `printf` that limits it to one language or the other.

Comment: @IjlalHussain - you certainly do not want to use to 100% non-portable `<conio.h>`. Your options are somewhat limited, unless you want to write your own I/O lib in assembly. You have `<cstdio>` or `<iostream>`, those are the only portable games in town. If you are still using DOS, then `<conio.h>`